# Diffeerent sitemap for each language

Tags: drupal-7, xml-sitemap

I have developed multilingual site, now i need XML sitemap for each language. In English it is working fine with all content types but in another languages it no links are shown except main URL. How can i achieve all content links in different language as well. Thanks in advance.

Module used: XML sitemap, Entity translation.

Answer (score -1):

looks like a bug of the XML Sitemap module...

look at [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1966512) Post! Hope that this will fix your issue!